# Save int[][] of RGB as image file

Tags: java, image, rgb, bufferedimage

I have array int[ ][ ] of RBG values of image and I need to store it to jpg file. I try to do this:

```
 BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(result));
 ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("/path/", "snap.jpg"));
```

But I have an int[ ][ ] not byte[ ] array. How to convert int[ ][ ] to byte[ ] without loss of values?

Comment: A BufferedImage can be created to use either int array or byte arrays if you use the appropriate image type constant when creating your image. I've never read the arrays directly in via ImageIO, but have gotten them from or put the arrays into the BufferedImage's raster's data buffer. Note that I am no pro at doing this, so please take this information with a grain of salt.

Comment: If you are concerned about data loss, why use a lossy compression like jpeg?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031316/creating-png-file-from-int-array-of-rgb-data/37501730

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even aside from the issue of `int[][]` vs. `byte[]`, your expression `ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(result));` does not really make sense, since it expects `result` to be the contents of an image file (not just the pixel values, but all of the headers, padding, etc., of some recognized image file format).

I think what you want is:

```
final int height = result.length;
final int width = result[0].length;
final BufferedImage image =
    new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        bufferedImage.setRGB(x, y, result[y][x]);
    }
}
```